Angular 17 and above: How to add a guard or protect empty path, redirectTo route
I am not able to add any guard or anything for redirectTo route in my case which is an empty path.
I am using MSAL for authentication, MSAL does provide a guard and its working for other routes.
So This is my situation.
Say whenever user enters base url like localhost:4200 in the browser then -
If user is not logged in (checking this from msal.isLoggedIn() in app comp) it should redirect them to Microsoft log in screen. This is happening but momentarily its loading dashboard screen.
If user is already logged it should check for user roles(I have a userRole service for this). if role has access to app then it should load ('' path means redirectTo dashboard) if not it should redirectTo "/insufficient-privilages". This is also happening but momentarily loading dashboard which I dont want.
I have tried to add canActivateChild just above children array like this
canActivateChild: [emptyPathRouteGuard]

I just couldnt figure out how to make this work. adding a guard to rediretTo route is not working or it should not as per docs. Need some help on this.
export const routes: Routes = [
         {
               path: '',
               loadComponent:() => layoutComp//this is layout component
               canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
               children: [
                          { 
                            path: '',
                            redirectTo: '/dashboard',      //this is where I am struggling
                            pathMatch: 'full',
                          },
                          {
                            path: 'reports',
                            loadComponent: () => //load component
                            canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                          },
                          {
                            path: 'dashboard',
                            loadComponent: () => //load component
                            canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                          }
                        ],
                

         },
         {
            path: 'insufficient-privileges',
            loadComponent: () => //load comp
        
          },
]


              


Versions of angular 17:
You can use canMatch  to conditionally trigger the redirect based on the authorization.
export function isAuthorizedCanMatchGuard() {
  const isAuthorized = inject(AuthService).isAuthorized;
  return isAuthorized;
}

export function isNotAuthorizedCanMatchGuard() {
  const isAuthorized = inject(AuthService).isAuthorized;
  return !isAuthorized;
}

export const routes: Routes = [
     {
           path: '',
           loadComponent:() => loadcomp //this is layout component
           canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
           children: [
                      { 
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
                        canMatch: [isAuthorizedCanMatchGuard],
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                      },
                      { 
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: 'insufficient-privileges',
                        canMatch: [isNotAuthorizedCanMatchGuard],
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                      },
                      {
                        path: 'reports',
                        loadComponent: () => //load component
                        canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                      },
                      {
                        path: 'dashboard',
                        loadComponent: () => //load component
                        canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                      }
                    ],
                 {
                    path: 'insufficient-privileges',
                    loadComponent: () => //load comp

                 },

     }
];


Versions of angular 18:
I just checked the docs for Route where redirectTo accepts a function for redirection. You can use this to conditionally do the redirection.
redirectTo ( string | RedirectFunction )

A URL or function that returns a URL to redirect to when the path matches.
Absolute if the URL begins with a slash (/) or the function returns a UrlTree, otherwise relative to the path URL.
The RedirectFunction is run in an injection context so it can call inject to get any required dependencies.
When not present, router does not redirect.

Since the original code not shared it would looks something like so.
function redirectBasedOnAuth(authService: AuthService) {
  return authService.isAuthenticated() ? 'dashboard' : 'insufficient-privileges';
}

export const routes: Routes = [
         {
               path: '',
               loadComponent:() => loadcomp //this is layout component
               canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
               children: [
                          { 
                            path: '',
                            redirectTo: (route, state) => redirectBasedOnAuth(route.injector.get(AuthService))
                            pathMatch: 'full',
                          },
                          {
                            path: 'reports',
                            loadComponent: () => //load component
                            canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                          },
                          {
                            path: 'dashboard',
                            loadComponent: () => //load component
                            canActivate: environment.sso ? [MsalGuard] : [],
                          }
                        ],
                     {
                        path: 'insufficient-privileges',
                        loadComponent: () => //load comp
        
                     },

         }
    ];

              

Article on Redirect Function

That's interesting! Thanks for taking time to understand the problem and recommending the solution.  I have read attached article before I think but I am wondering if this applies to Angular version 17.

@Rakeys you also have canMatchFn which can be used to do the same thing and redirect based on this function same logic as above though, there needs to be two redirects each with their own can match fn

@Rakeys updated my answer for angular 17

Is the order of the routes matter here? it seems based on your update above I have updated canMatch but angular router doesn't recognize it? I found some info on this but bit confused on what's going on with this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75475333/using-redirectto-and-canmatch-in-routing-config-to-redirect-users-based-on-p

And also this one https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49145

@Rakeys put a debugger on the function and see if is called and returns true or false correctly, if not please share a simple stackblitz replicating the issue for checking
